# Xsd.exe generates buggy implementation of <xs:list>

Tags: c#, code-generation, xsd.exe

This is an example of what **Xsd.exe** generates (also Xsd2Code but using generic List<>).

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class ItemQuantity 
{

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Units;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()] // <-- this is the bug
    public double[] Text;   // <-- this is the bug corresponding to a <xs:list itemType=xs:double/> in the schema
}
```

I am dealing with a very large schema, which uses several times xs:list for different primitives...

And all these Text properties that are not string[] (rather double[] decimal[]) all lead to this exception at run-time *when used with XmlSerializer*: (I translate it in english) The member Text cannot be coded with the attribute XmlText. You can use the attribute XmlText with primitives, enums, string arrays, or XmlNode arrays.

What do you advise me ?

Comment: Have you experimented with http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/.

Comment: No, I just went on the page... what detered me from trying was the fact that I'm stuck to .net 3.5 and that Linq2Xsd v2.0 is for .net 4.0... But I'm gonna try the former version this afternoon Linq2Xsd v1.0 that can goes for .net 3.5... this is an idea to try, sure. thx.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the xsd.exe generated code and put

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Double",typeof(double), IsNullable = false)]
```

instead of

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
```

and as far as I can judge... it does behaves much better....

ie

```
<Test><Double>0.1</Double><Double>0.2</Double><Double>0.8</Double><Double>0.505</Double></Test>
```

But I should ensure that enclosing all that list in the Test tag is still valid with my schema...